# Does the invertible sheaf to line bundle correspondence commute with taking duals?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, and $F$ an invertible sheaf on $X$. Let $L_F\rightarrow X$ be the corresponding line bundle. Is the line bundle associated to $F^\vee$ just the dual of $L_F$?

Is this obvious? Does anyone have a good reference for this sort of thing?

Comment: Yes, because the assignment $F \mapsto \mathbf{V}(F)$ defining the equivalence between locally free sheaves and vector bundles is symmetric monoidal.

Comment: @Adeel Do you have a reference?

Comment: No, but you can just compare the functors of points of $\mathbf{V}(F \otimes G)$ and $\mathbf{V}(F) \otimes \mathbf{V}(G)$.  Recall that $\mathbf{V}(F)$ represents the functor that sends an $X$-scheme $f : Y \to X$ to the set $Hom_{O_Y}(f^*(F), O_Y)$.

Comment: EGA II.1.7. In particular, EGA II.1.7.9 and II.1.7.10 contain the statement you want (which says sections of the associated vector bundle are sections of the dual of your qcoh sheaf).